# Sync SMS inbox and Google Voice

Tags: sms, google-voice

I use Google Voice for my phone, for voicemail and SMS. It is very convenient to read and send texts from my computer, but if I do not use the Google Voice app on my phone (which, unfortunately, is rather ill-designed in my opinion), the texts I send from voice.google.com or the Chrome extension (or, incidentally, the Google Voice app on my phone) do not show up in my SMS thread, in the stock messaging app or any replacement one (I use GoSMS).

Is there a way to make Google Voice sync with these somehow, so I can see the messages I send through Google Voice without using one of their apps?

Comment: If you have service with Sprint you can, but otherwise I don't think there's a way.

Comment: I do have service with Sprint. In fact, my Google voice number _is_ my actual Sprint number, and the inboxes still do not sync.

Comment: Hm, I thought they used to sync up for me when I used Sprint's GV integration. Maybe I'm misremembering.

Comment: did you have to manually set it like that or did it just act that way automatically?

Comment: I thought it just did it automatically after I did the integration stuff, but I switched to Verizon about a month ago so I can't test it anymore :-/ I definitely remember getting all of my SMSes in the GV app (which was annoying since they were all marked "unread" even though I had responded in Handcent), but maybe it never worked the other way around.

Comment: yeah, it works if I respond in GoSMS and then view them through GV, but if I respond via GV, then they don't show up in GoSMS :/